# Can light propagate in the absence of electric and magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

It has been established that light or other forms of electromagnetic radiation needs electric and magnetic fields in order to propagate. What would happen if it were possible to shield an area from both electric and magnetic fields and also to create a vacuum in the given space. Theoretically it should be possible to shield an area from both electric and magnetic fields. If the area so shielded is a vacuum, so much the better. The question is not whether the light will be visible if viewed side-ways on, but a question of whether, in the absence of electric and magnetic fields, light will be able to propagate at all. Take a Faraday cage for instance, no electric or magnetic fields should be able to exist inside it. Therefore, if an electrical conductor is moved about in a Faraday cage, it is possible that under such circumstances, no induction current would be detectable. Imagine that the space in which the vacuum is created is a metal box. If the metal sides of the box are thick enough, it might be possible to reroute all of the lines of flux so that they do not penetrate to the other side of the metal. The metal would serve a similar purpose for the electric field, confining it to the surface.  The presence of a vacuum would further increase the efficacy of the experiment since, EMR would not be able to travel from molecule to molecule or atom to atom. While a perfect vacuum would be difficult, if not impossible to create, it might be possible to come near enough to it for it not to matter.  Is this possible?

Comment: Do you know that light consists of electromagnetic fields? So if you introduce light you immediately change your situation without electromagnetic fields into one that does have those fields. I'm not sure if there is any question left.

Answer (score 1):

A photon traveling through space creates its own transient E and M excitations as it goes along. In fact it is the interactive self-propagation of those field disturbances which *constitutes* a photon in the first place.

Note that there is a difference between a *field* and its *excitations*. The field exists everywhere at all times whereas the excitations of the field get created and destroyed. So inside a faraday cage there may well be no *excitations* of wavelength ~bigger than the cage, but the underlying *field* is still there, and an excitation source *inside* the cage will still propagate inside the cage.